# remove lines, no borders, from excel's worksheet

Tags: excel

into a downloaded excel 2010 file the are 2 lines that i don't knwo how to remove.

no borders is set for the cells around the two lines.

also i select all cells with CTRL+A then into update ribbon, delete -> delete all with no success.

each cell around the lines have no border, background or formatting.

what more can i check to remove the two lines ?

[image: excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `Visualizza` tab look like? Suspect It's frozen panes but could be something else.

[image]

Comment: yep, unfreeze panes removed the 2 lines.